# Envoy Access Log Multi Filter exclude

Tags: filter, envoyproxy, access-log

I am trying to filter out a log_type_filter when it has the status code 200. I need to know how to exclude this exact match and not all of the log_type_filter. Here is what I have

```yaml
filter: 
  and_filter:
    filters:
      - log_type_filter: 
        op: EQ
        value: 
          default_value: envoy_access_log
        exclude: true
      - or_filter:
        filters:
          - status_code_filter: 
            comparison: 
              op: GE
              value: 
                default_value: 201
          - status_code_filter: 
            comparison: 
              op: LE
              value: 
                default_value: 199
```

*Edit*
I misread the documentation where it states

> Performs a logical “and” operation on the result of each filter in filters. Filters are evaluated sequentially and if one of them returns false, the filter returns false immediately.

So i believe I should just need to do

```yaml
filter: 
  and_filter:
    filters:
      - log_type_filter: 
          comparison: 
            op: EQ
            value: envoy_access_log
      - status_code_filter: 
          comparison: 
            op: EQ
            value: 200
```

Please let me know if you see something invalid. I do not have the opportunity to test this at this time.